# Import image as a background in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android

How should I import .png image that suppose to be the background of my activity? I selected ***drawable*** folder from the project panel then opened the New menu: '*Image Asset*' , but this option is for importing icons so I guess it's not right decision (I need to import an image to be spread over all the screen background). I then chosed instead the option **'scaled drawble'** (maybe it's not part of the default Android Studio installation but provided as part of some plugin I installed)

This option actually imported the .png to be under my project in different scales (mdpi, hdpi etc.) but **is it the the most recommended option in order to add background images to Android Studio?** Because I noticed that the xhdpi and xxhdpi became in bigger KB size than the original size of the file that was imported (doesn't make sense that its size is bigger than the source)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the drawable folder, and optimize imports, then it shows the path of drawable folder, open this path in Windows Explorer, copy any image to the path

Answer (score 0):

I am using that plug-in too. but problem is plugin uses original image as xhdpi and scales others. this means if your image is very big for instance ldpi will be very big too and file sizes will be too large. I am trying to find standard image sizes.

1. I think using a big image that is big enough for xxxhdpi and paste it in drawable-xxxhdpi or drawable folder is safe way.
2. if your image is good to scale(I mean something like .svg images) or just don't care about scaling paste it in xhdpi and system will scale it.